# Identifying the rightmost character in an NSString

Tags: objective-c

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have an `NSString` that I stored in an array

```
NSString *obsSchoolName = [[self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0] obsSchoolNameSaved];
```

How can I then check the rightmost character?

The reason being **obsSchoolName** will have been stored with a $ character at the end to show some previous procedure has been completed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hasSuffix is what you want:

> hasSuffix:
>   Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string matches the ending characters of the receiver.

[hasSuffix](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rightmost entry of any array (and a string basically is a character array) by getting the item at the array's total length - 1:

```
NSString *last = [yourString substringFromIndex:[yourString length] - 1];
```

Comment: `hasSuffix` is better because you don't have to handle the case of an empty string (which would crash with your code).

Comment: @omz that's true, `hasSuffix` would probably be a beeter solution. My example is just another way of getting the rightmost char by hand. You'd probably want to check if the string is empty first. I left this out to keep it brief.